# XSLT split string by charlength and call function for each substring

Tags: xml, xslt, substring, xslt-2.0, tokenize

For example if you have a string that does not have a fixed length, but is always in increments of 2, how should I break up the string into multiple parts and call a template for each of the substring, as each of them correspond to a different text.

```
<root>
<Data>
<ErrorNumber>12345678</ErrorNumber>
</Data>
</root>
```

For the error codes suppose

```
12 = "Test 1"
34 = "Test 2"
56 = "Test 3"
78 = "Test4"
```

So that function should call this function and get the output

```
<xsl:template name="GetErrorCode">
<xsl: param name = "ErrorCode"/>
<xsl: if test = "$ErrorCode = '12'">
<xsl:text> Test 1 </xsl:test>
</xsl:if>
</xsl template>
```

So basically if I pass 12345678 as param I would get

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 4
```

As Output

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `tokenize()`, since that takes a pattern for the separator, not for the tokens; and your scenario doesn't involve a separator.

Comment: You could use `tokenize()` after adding a separator. Something like: `tokenize(replace(ErrorNumber,'(..)','$1-'),'-')[string()]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use XPath substring to extract the fixed blocks and assign them to XSLT variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="A"  select="substring(/root/Data/ErrorNumber, 1, 2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="B" select="substring(/root/Data/ErrorNumber, 3, 2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="C"  select="substring(/root/Data/ErrorNumber, 5, 2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="D" select="substring(/root/Data/ErrorNumber, 7, 2)"/>
```

And from there use the variables in your test.

The template below can be used if the size of the codes are not of fixed length:

```
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($text) = 2">
            <token><xsl:value-of select="$text"/></token>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <token><xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, 2)"/></token>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 3, string-length($text)-2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It will return a node-set containing one or more  elements, for example, if you call it with:

```
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/root/Data/ErrorNumber" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Where ErrorNumber is 12345678, you get a variable `$tokens` containing:

```
<token>12</token>
<token>34</token>
<token>56</token>
<token>78</token>
```

Then you can call your template passing `$tokens/token[2]` to obtain the desired result.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but the length of the Error Code is not always fixed. It could be 12 or 1234 or 123456, in increments of 2 so it needs to be dynamic

Comment: Yes. You can do that setting the variable recursively. I'll include it above.